# Get Shipping rates for a product - Shopify

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I couldn't found an endpoint(Shopify API REST or Shopify GraphQL) to get the shipping rates available for a product, quantity, and zip code.
The idea is a user in the PDP(Product detail page) select a quantity for a product, type a zip code and after that, I need to render the information (name of shipping and price) in PDP. This functionality is using the Shopify Rates not CarrierService custom

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this was to use Draft Orders to simulate the Order and see the cost of Shipping